# Largest set where the series converges pointwisely

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Find the largest set where the following series converges pointwisely?
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+nx^4} . $$ Here what I did;

if $x=0  , $  then obviously series diverges to $\infty$,

if $x=1, $ then series diverges since $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $ diverges.

I found this series converges only if $ x=n $. Is this statement true? If not, how can I find the largest set ($ =D$) in which the series convergent?

Comment: How can $\;x\;$ equal the running index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|x| \le 1$, then $1+nx^4 \le 1 + n$, so the series diverges by comparison with the harmonic series.

If $|x| \ge 1$, then $1 + nx^4 \le x^4 + nx^4 = x^4(1+n)$, and so the series diverges (again by comparison with the harmonic series).

So the largest set is $\varnothing$.